# Finding relation schema and functional dependency

Tags: dependencies, relation

- Consider following relation EMP_PROJ relation
  (SSN,Pnumber, Hours,Ename, Pname,Plocation)

1. SSN is social security number of employee which is unique
2. Pnumber is project number which is unique
3. Hours is number of hours employee works on project
4. Ename is Employee name
5. Pname is project name
6. Plocation is project location.
   (a) Convert the above relation into 2NF.
   (b) List the functional dependencies.

I think that I will get the functional dependencies and relation schema for this relation